# How to use 'should' for asserting a primitive data type in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, chai

How can I use Cypress's `should` (https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should) to assert a primary type object (not `expect` or `assert` commands)

I would like to understand better why this code

```
it('', function() {
    const x = 200
    x.should('be.greaterThan', 100)
})
```

returns `x.should is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

`should` is for the `cy` commands.

So if really you want to do it with your example, you can do:

```
it('', function() {
    const x = 200
    cy.wrap(x).should('be.greaterThan', 100)
})
```

But in our case, I would keep `expect`